# How do I put special chars in my user name?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Yes I know the user name textbox says that only `[0-9 A-Z a-z]` are allowed but I see users all the time with things like this:

`Johannes Rössel`

I know there probably using foreign keyboard layouts, but I was just wondering if I can add them to my name.

Comment: I think you got it now :)

Comment: @Jeff: I was hoping you didn't care that I was abusing the special char's. But hey, this question might actually be helpful to someone in a foreign country.

Comment: Your name looks infected.

Comment: I recently started learning C (that could be the reason). BTW Why the heck isn't anything in C documented!!! EH!!!

**I'll take your comment as a compliment though.**

Comment: yeah, now it's annoying. Can you switch it back? I don't mind if you do it here, but on Stack Overflow, it's not welcome.

Comment: Sorry. I'll change it. But it was fun. And I'm breaking it back out on April Fools day! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always change up your own keyboard layout using Windows. Or you could just insert the special characters yourself if you know the alt-codes.

Comment: I'm on linux (ubuntu). I tried to use the char map in linux but it just inserted things like \u00dd.

Comment: Simple answer: stop using ubuntu :)

Comment: I've got windows 7 but I don't want to reboot (even if it is faster then vista's reboot time). ;-)

Comment: you can use compose keys, compose key tends to be right-alt+shift , and [ralt+shift][o]["] ( seperate presses ) becomes ö . Firefox should also support UIM under linux, and [ctrl+shift+u] will start unicode input. [ctrl+shift+u][0][F][0][space] emits this: ð

Comment: @Kent: Those char's aren't accepted by the SO name box.

Comment: @TheTXI: I rebooted. How awesome does my name look?

Comment: It turns out I couldn't find any special chars for the letter `V`.

Comment: how about my name ;)

Comment: @sɐdɹǝpuɐxǝʃɐ: Very Nice!

Answer (score 1):

The edit page allows rich (unicode) entry for usernames. Try editing your user profile.

The "ask a question" page did not not, until recently. This was an unintended side effect of JavaScript client-side validation.

Comment: When you say "rich" exactly what do you mean? I've tried using XML decimal entity's but when you type &#345; it recognizes it as 6 chars, so you get up to the 25 limit very soon.

Comment: I also tried @Kent Fredric's suggestion and it wouldn't allow those either.